# How to embed pdf.js in a fancybox

Tags: javascript, pdf, fancybox, embed, pdfobject

Fancybox is great but the default pdf implementation does not work very well because support, look and feel depends on OS, browser and adobe installation.
PDF.js solves that by using a web standards-based platform for parsing and rendering PDFs. How to embed pdf.js viewer inside a fancybox?

Answer (score 5):

Here's my solution how you can use pdf.js together with fancybox. It works x-browsers (at least the ones I tried), automatically & dynamically scales to browser view size and looks nice! The exact loading behavior can be a bit different between browsers though.

You will need to include jquery, fancybox and pdf.js:

- http://jquery.com/download/
- http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/
- https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Setup-pdf.js-in-a-website

[image]

If you want to embed pdf.js inside a static div instead of a fancybox, please have a look at https://pdfobject.com/

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Add jQuery library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./includes/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Add fancyBox main JS and CSS files -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./includes/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./includes/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var pdfOpenParams = "#page=1&pagemode=none"; //pagemode=none,bookmarks,thumbs

        $(document).ready(function () {
            //Fancybox settings
            $(".fancybox-pdf").fancybox({
                type: 'iframe',
                padding: 0,
                openEffect: 'fade',
                openSpeed: 150,
                closeEffect: 'fade',
                closeSpeed: 150,
                closeClick: true,
                width: '60%',
                height: '100%',
                maxWidth: '100%',
                maxHeight: '100%',
                iframe: {
                    preload: false
                },
                //Define PDF.js viewer with optional parameters
                beforeLoad: function () {
                    var url = $(this.element).attr("href");
                    this.href = "./includes/js/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=" + url + pdfOpenParams;
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a class="fancybox-pdf" href="http://localhost/pdf/pdf-sample.pdf">View PDF</a>
</body>
</html>
```